Detect Azure Application Gateway downtime?
One of my application gateways is, intermittantly, becoming unresponsive to requests. There are larger, noticeable (by the users), periods of downtime and more very short ones (a few minutes only).
I'm detecting the downtime of the AG (rather than network issues/destination server downtime) by all of the AG's metric graphs missing data for that period:

After each long period of downtime there is a CPU usage spike which I've been interpreting as the effort to "come back up". Shorter periods of downtime often are not followed by a CPU usage spike.
The AGs are all v1, tier "Standard", and "Small" sku with a single instance count. The throughput is generally very low and the cpu usage is not high under typical load (nor noticeably prior to the outages).
I have no understanding of why these outages are occurring. My assumption is "gremlins at MS" (the throughput isn't particularly high prior to the outages).
I'm attempting to mitigate by upping the instance count or the sku size. I still had some significant outages with a "medium" deployment but another with 2x small instances is, as far as I can see, without outages so far. I've seen that azure offers no SLA unless the deployment is 2xmedium, but we'd rather avoid this expense.
Question: How can I detect such outages? Manual inspection is slow and on demand. I can't see how to setup an alert to trigger on missing data and none of the log queries appear to be relevant.
